# xcopy always override files

Tags: backup, robocopy, xcopy

this is the situation:
File System is corrupt and files are damaged. ChkDsk repaired the filesystem but files are still damaged.

So I want to use a Backup and overwrite all files **without exception.**
Backup is about 12TB, but since the Destination has been in use there is a small delta of new files and modified files on there.
Backup should overwrite all files in Destination but keep the newly ones, the delta.
I know changes to modified files will be lost - but thats ok.

Corrupted files and Backup files look the same - same size, mostly same timestamps, same attributes, same acl...

I couldn't find a tool to copy and overwrite withoput exception.

- Tried robocoy: robocopy source dest /COPY:DT /e /z /im /is /it /zb.
  Doesn't really copy when equal files

-Tried xcopy: xcopy source dest /h /i /c /e /r /y /z
Doens't copy when dest file is newer
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2H96f.png)
Maybe use /d parameter here with an really old date?

Any Ideas?